# Nextjs dev server has become dramatically slow after migrating in monorepo with PNPM

Tags: next.js, webpack-dev-server, pnpm-workspace

I did a switch to a project to build a consistent mono repo.

I have a pretty classical structure with apps and package folders.

Inside the packages folder, I have a bunch of small functions-loaded packages and some type definitions I consume in the app/frontend and app/backend apps.

The app/frontend app is a next.js app, recently migrated to next.js 13.

The mon repo works in a marvelous way and I'm very satisfied with the neat code organization.

But, when I run the old npm run dev to build the app, I notice a profound slowing in the reactiveness of the app, making the development a nightmare (40-60 secs for build, 3-10 secs for the interactive UI to update).

Is there a rudimental error I'm not seeing?

Here is some context:

**apps/frontend/next.config.js**

```js
const nextConfig ={
    ...
    transpilePackages: ["@my-repo/package-A", "@my-repo/package-B", "@my-repo/package-C"],
    reactStrictMode: true,
    swcMinify: true, 
    ... 
};
```

**apps/frontend/package.json**

```json
"dependencies": {
    "...": "...",
    "@my-repo/package-A": "workspace:*",
    "@my-repo/package-B": "workspace:*",
    "@my-repo/package-C": "workspace:*",
    "...": "..."
}
```

If I launch from pnpm in the root folder the script "pnpm --filter=@my-repo/frontend dev" or an old-fashioned npm run dev in the frontend folder, it's completely irrelevant.

Any clues?

Thank you very much.

I expect lesser degradation of the dev server speed.

Maybe it could be the "workspace:*" reference to the custom packages that make the next dev server manipulate too many files? IDK.

Comment: Hey, any luck getting past this? I am running into this as well

Comment: Same situation in here